# the value of __block variable is not changed

Tags: iphone, multithreading, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks, avurlasset

The code below will load the value of the asset asynchronously. I wait for it using while loop.

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:aAudioLink options: nil];
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys 
                 completionHandler:^{                                           
                canExit = TRUE;
                         }];

    while (canExit == FALSE) {
        // NSLog (@"canExist = FALSE");     
    }

    NSLog(@"canExist = TRUE");
```

If NSLog statement is commented like the code above, the last NSLog will not be called.
If NSLog statement is NOT commented, the last NSLog is called.

The block and the code outside the block run on different threads and both of which are not main thread.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: first of all, you should never do this, it totally defeats the purpose of the method being asynchronous. Second, it depends on how canExit is declared. Blocks handle variables in a different way, you can either pass them as a copy, or as the address and they also depend on the scope. And third, the problem I believe is that your code might be getting optimized by the compiler, without that nslog it might be thinking that its an irrelevant call and might be taking it out. This is just a wild guess tho, which is why im adding it as a comment =p

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldnt be using a while loop for this. Recently i was dealing with an application in which i had to make use of AVAsset to generate thumbnail image for the asset.i ended up using a dispatch semaphore for blocking the thread until the image was generated asynchronously.

Why cant you  try the following.

```
 dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

 AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:aAudioLink options: nil];

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys 
             completionHandler:^{                                           
            canExit = TRUE;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
             }];
    });



dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(sema);
```

It should work if I'm right.